# AWS athena - How to filter json array?

Tags: sql, json, presto, amazon-athena

Trying to filter a json array for a specific object

```
select json_extract(
    '{"coll":[{"key":"color","value":"red"},{"key":"other","value":"whatever"}]}',
    '$.coll[?(@.type == ''color'')]'
)
```

but AWS athena just says

> ```
> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON path: '$.coll[?(@.type == 'color')]'
> ```

Trying the above in a tool like https://jsonpath.com/ seems to work.

Is this syntax correct and athena just does not support this kind of json path?

Comment: at least, this way of querying json object is not specified in either of the pages mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-JSON.html

Comment: Probably not supported..
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/scalar/JsonExtract.java
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/scalar/JsonPathTokenizer.java

Comment: as a workaround, this question suggests using UNNEST. Not as clean but should get you what you need. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48381732/220997